# Navigation Drawer Lagging, Images

Tags: android

In my applications there is a custom ListView which contains some texviews and an ImageView, for each element of the lV the image is different, because of theese images my Nav Drawers lags a lot.
What I noticed is that it doesn't lag if I set the same image for every element, if there are two different images it starts lagging, Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

obviously the program doesn't load an Image already loaded so it takes no memory if you put many equal images in the same activity, it only takes more memory when you add different ones, didn't think about that before, Just resized images and worked fine